# Socket: Protocol not supported error

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I am currently working on Raw socket programming using C language in Linux. When I compile the program, no errors are detected. However, while running the program, I get "Socket: Protocol not supported" error. The code I am using is given below. Can someone please help me find the solution to the problem?

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/tcp.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#define P 25

struct tcph {
unsigned short int th_sport;
unsigned short int th_dport;
 unsigned int th_seq;
 unsigned int th_ack;
 unsigned char th_x2:4, th_off:4;
 unsigned char th_flags;
 unsigned short int th_win;
 unsigned short int th_sum;
 unsigned short int th_urp;
};

int main()
{
 int sock,connected,bytes_recieved,true=1;
char send_data[1024],recv_data[1024];
struct sockaddr_in server_addr,client_addr;
int sin_size;

char datagram[4096];
struct tcph *tcph = (struct tcph *) datagram;
tcph->th_sport = htons (1234);
tcph->th_dport = htons (P);
tcph->th_seq = random ();
tcph->th_ack = 0;
tcph->th_x2 = 0;
tcph->th_off = 0;       
tcph->th_flags = 0; 
tcph->th_win = htonl (65535);   
tcph->th_sum = 0;
tcph->th_urp = 0;

if((sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,0))==-1)
{
perror("Socket");
exit(1);
}
if(setsockopt(sock,IPPROTO_TCP,IP_HDRINCL,&true,sizeof(true))==-1)
{
perror("Setsockopt");
exit(1);
}
server_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port=htons(9392);
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;
bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);
if(bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr))==-1)
{
perror("Unable to bind");
exit(1);
}
if(listen(sock,5)==-1)
{
perror("Listen");
exit(1);
}
printf("\nTCP Server waiting for client on port 9392");
fflush(stdout);
while(1)
{
 sin_size=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
 connected=accept(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&sin_size);
 printf("\nI got a connection from (%s,%d)",inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),ntohs(client_addr.sin_port));
 while(1)
{
printf("\nSEND (q or Q to quit):");
scanf("%s",send_data);
if(strcmp(send_data,"q")==0||strcmp(send_data,"Q")==0)
{
send(connected,send_data,strlen(send_data),0);
close(connected);
exit(0);
}
else
send(connected,send_data,strlen(send_data),0);
bytes_recieved=recv(connected,recv_data,1024,0);
recv_data[bytes_recieved]='\0';
if(strcmp(recv_data,"q")==0||strcmp(recv_data,"Q")==0)
{
close(connected);
break;
}
else
{
printf("\nRECIEVED DATA=%s",recv_data);
}
fflush(stdout);
}
}
close(sock);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out D.J. Bernstein's tcpserver (see http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/tcpserver.html). Basically, you can simply run your C program under tcpserver, and tcpserver will handle everything as far as setting up the sockets, listing for incoming connections on whatever port you are using, etc. When an incoming connection arrives on the port that you specify, tcpserver will spawn an instance of your program and pipe incoming info from the client to your program's STDIN, and pipe outgoing info from your program's STDOUT back to the client. This way, you can concentrate on your program's core logic (and simply read/write to stdout/stdin), and let tcpserver handle all of the heavy lifting as far as the sockets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`listen()` is supported for TCP sockets, not SOCK_RAW sockets. ["The sockfd argument is a file descriptor that refers to a socket of type SOCK_STREAM or SOCK_SEQPACKET."](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen)